# How to find element count of certain interval in a list in java?

Tags: java, list

I need to find element count of interval [-100;100] in a circular doubly linked list in java. The size of list is unknown. How can I do this? Could anyone give me an example code?

Comment: You should try something yourself, then if you have problems, ask about those specific problems. Stack Overflow is a poor place to ask someone to just write code for you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @Toms! Could you please elaborate with a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you want to achieve? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the stupid answer, but the only way to do this is to iterate over the complete list and count the number of elements in the given interval.

It is not important that the list is doubly linked and circular.

You can probably use something like:

```
counter = 0;
for (ListElement e : list) {
    if (e >= -100 && e <= 100) counter++;
}
```

Comment: @Toms: Depends on how the list is implemented, maybe post some code.

Comment: For now the only question is what to write after for (int i = 0; i < list.getSize(); i++) in the IF brackets?